# Passing multiple params through vue-router with one of them used in the URL

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am trying to pass data from one route to another. However, I need to pass an ID and title to the child route and use only the title in the URL but not the ID. I will use the ID to fetch data. I have read everywhere and I cannot think of a solution to my problem.

Example:

Let's say we are at route called "Library", where we have different books. When clicking on one of the books, I want to go to another route, which will display the book title in the URL and have the ID usable for data fetching. How can I do that?

I have found how to do dynamic URL matching, which I can use for the title display but then I cannot pass the ID:

`<router-link :to="{path: '/Book/' + book.title}">`

I have also found how to pass parameters using named routes but then how do I use the title in the URL?

`<router-link :to="{name: 'Book', params: {title: book.title}}">`

I am sure I am missing something here but I am not entirely sure what.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `props`:

router/index.js:

```
routes: [
  { path: '/Library/:title', name: 'Book', component: Book, props: true },
  ...
]
```

navigation:

```
:to="{ name: 'Book', params: { title: book.title }, props: { id: book.id } }"
```

`Book.vue`

```
export default {
  props: {
    id: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  }
}
```

Instead of `props: true` in router definition you can pass defaults, i.e:

```
..., props: { id: '1' }
```

Be weary of using title in url, it might need escaping. I know it's good for SEO, but ids are safer.

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, I get an error in Book.vue - "Missing required prop: "id"". It seems to not pass it to the Book component.

Comment: I solved it finally! Everything is as you did it except in the navigation, instead of adding props, I just included the id in the params, so it looks like this: 

` :to="{ name: 'Book', params: { title: book.title, id: book.id }}" `

Thank you for your help!

Comment: @VBobby, it should work with `props` as well. The error you were getting means you have `<book>` elements without an `id` in your markup. You could change the `id` prop from `required` to default: `''`. But I assumed you don't want a `<book>` without an `id`. Glad you solved it.